# How to make the test name match the controller name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have this `users_controller`

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The file is in `app/controllers/api/v1/`

And my test is :

```
class Api::V1::UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test '#show displays the specific user' do 
    @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)

    get :show, id: @user.id
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

The file is in `test/controllers/api/v1`

When I run the test I get this error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Api
/Users/Ahmad/rails_apps/json_api/test/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

What's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss

```
require 'test_helper'
```

at the top of your file. Give a try.